# PyTorch: Expected input batch_size (12) to match target batch_size (64)

Tags: python, pycharm, pytorch

I tried out PyTorch and wanted to write a program for MNIST. But, I got the error message:

> Expected input batch_size (12) to match target batch_size (64)

I searched for a solution but I don't understand what's wrong with my code.

```
#kwargs is empty because I don't use cuda
kwargs = {}
train_data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('data', train=True, download=True,
                    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,),(0.3081,))])),
    batch_size=64, shuffle=True, **kwargs)

test_data = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('data', train=False,
                    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,),(0.3081,))])),
    batch_size=64, shuffle=True, **kwargs)

class Netz(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Netz, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,10, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=5)
        self.conv_dropout = nn.Dropout2d()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(320, 60)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(60, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.conv_dropout(x)
        x = F.max_pool2d(x, 2)
        x = F.relu(x)
        print(x.shape)
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 320)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return F.log_softmax(x, dim=0)

model = Netz()

optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.1, momentum=0.8)
def train(epoch):
    model.train()

    for batch_id, (data, target) in enumerate(train_data):
        data = Variable(data)
        target = Variable(target)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        out = model(data)
        print(out.shape)
        criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss = criterion(out, target)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'. format(
            epoch, batch_id * len(data), len(train_data.dataset),
            100. * batch_id / len(train_data), loss.data[0]))
```

The output should show the epoch and some other information. Actually, I print out the shape of my tensor but I don't know what's wrong. Here is the error message:

```
/home/michael/Programmierung/Python/PyTorch/venv/bin/python /home/michael/Programmierung/Python/PyTorch/mnist.py
torch.Size([64, 20, 4, 4])
torch.Size([12, 10])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/michael/Programmierung/Python/PyTorch/mnist.py", line 69, in <module>
    train(epoch)
  File "/home/michael/Programmierung/Python/PyTorch/mnist.py", line 60, in train
    loss = criterion(out, target)
  File "/home/michael/Programmierung/Python/PyTorch/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 493, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/michael/Programmierung/Python/PyTorch/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 942, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/home/michael/Programmierung/Python/PyTorch/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2056, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "/home/michael/Programmierung/Python/PyTorch/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1869, in nll_loss
    .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
ValueError: Expected input batch_size (12) to match target batch_size (64).

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The error occurs because your model output, `out`, has shape `(12, 10)`, while your `target` has a length of 64.

Since you are using a batch size of 64 and predicting the probabilities of 10 classes, you would expect your model output to be of shape `(64, 10)`, so clearly there is something amiss in the `forward()` method.

Going through it line by line and noting the size of `x` at every step, we can try to find out what is going wrong:

```
    ...
    # x.shape = (64, 20, 4, 4) at this point as seen in your print statement
    x = x.view(-1, 320)             # x.shape = (64, 320)
    x = self.fc1(x)                 # x.shape = (64, 60)
    x = x.view(-1, 320)             # x.shape = (12, 320)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))         # x.shape = (12, 60)
    x = self.fc2(x)                 # x.shape = (12, 10)
    return F.log_softmax(x, dim=0)  # x.shape = (12, 10)
```

What you actually most likely want is:

```
    ...
    # x.shape = (64, 20, 4, 4) at this point as seen in your print statement
    x = x.view(-1, 320)             # x.shape = (64, 320)
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))         # x.shape = (64, 60)
    x = self.fc2(x)                 # x.shape = (64, 10)
    return F.log_softmax(x, dim=1)  # x.shape = (64, 10)
```

**Note:** While not related to the error, note also that you want to softmax over `dim=1` since that is the dimension that contains the logits for the classes.